# gdalwarp clipping produces a black image

Tags: qgis, gdal, gdalwarp, geotiff-tiff

I have a large radar image (1.1GB) from Sentinel-1 and I need to make it smaller so that I can process it without my memory crashing. Using QGIS I generated the command to mask an image based on a shapefile using Raster > Extraction > Clipper.

The command was `gdalwarp -q -cutline my_shapefile -tr 0.000107418644212 0.000107418644212 -of GTiff my_sourceTIF my_destinationTIF`.

When I run this command in my OSX terminal it generates a new TIF image. But when I open it in QGIS, the image covers the same area as before except the whole thing is now black.

Comment: Are you sure that your source raster and shapefile align if On-The-Fly-reprojection is turned **OFF**?

Comment: Resolution maybe? Are you in lat/lon or meters?

Comment: @AndreJ I am not familiar with on the fly reprojection, but in QGIS the shapefile is in the location that I want it to be in relation to the raster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html especially from here:

> Polygon cutlines may be used as a mask to restrict the area of the
>   destination file that may be updated, including blending. If the OGR
>   layer containing the cutline features has no explicit SRS, the cutline
>   features must be in the SRS of the destination file. When writing to a
>   not yet existing target dataset, its extent will be the one of the
>   original raster unless -te or -crop_to_cutline are specified.

QGIS seems to create a command that does not adjust the extents of the output. Adding `-crop_to_cutline` should help:

> -crop_to_cutline:
>       (GDAL >= 1.8.0) Crop the extent of the target dataset to the extent of the cutline.

What is the bit depth of your Sentinel-1 image? High bit depth images appear often black on screen if all the data are near the lower end of the range. Adjusting image properties with QGIS by applying a min-max stretch helps in this case.

Comment: The -crop_to_cutline solved the clipping problem, but it is still all black. Could you explain more about the min-max stretch?

Comment: I found the min-max stretch option and that was already applied. The solution to the blackness was to compress the image as described in the answers here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144962/creating-compressed-geotiff-with-qgis-clipper-tool

Comment: Compression with "deflate" should not have any effect on the pixel values but good that you can see the image now even I wonder why.