# While exporting GeoTIFF doubles in size

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, export, rgb

I was given an RGB GeoTIFF orthomosaic image that is just over 10GB. I pulled it into QGIS and tried clipping it to get under 10GB (to use in another program that only allows up to 10GB).

Though when I clip it or do any other process, the output file size is over double of the orginal (24GB). I tried setting the zero values to null, but that has minimal effect. I need to keep the image as an RGB, so I cannot export it as a `jpeg` or `png`.

Has anyone else run into this problem and solved it, if yes then how?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/144962/2856

Comment: JPEG and png can certainly be RGB but your issue is in creating the output as uncompressed while the input is compressed. I suggest to create tiled GeoTIFF with JPEG compression. Test with different quality settings for finding a combination of size and quality that is best for you.

Comment: @user2856 I looked through that post, but am having trouble finding the correct commands to input. I've tried `-co COMPRESS=LZW -co BIGTIFF=YES` and `-co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co BIGTIFF=YES`. Files are still doubling in size.

Comment: @user30184 so something like `-co COMPRESS=JPEG -co BIGTIFF=YES -co TILED=YES`?

Comment: LZW and deflate are lossless and compress aerial photos typically about 30-50%. JPEG is lossy and compresses much more. Try also `-co photometric=ycbcr`. Have you checked the compression used in the original file with gdalinfo? I hope you have already read https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html.

Comment: Yes, I have been looking through the compression types in that document. I think I might have it figured out. If I need some more help, I'll post a new question. Cheers!