# How to do JPEG compression for TIFF file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, jpg, compression

I am trying to compress a large Tiff file of an Interpolated DEM (TIN interpolation) that that I created in QGIS. I am using the tool warp (reproject) listed under projections under ´Raster´ in the Menu bar. but I get the following errors:

**Warning 1: /vsimem/gtiffdataset_jpg_tmp_00000227B61DE130: NBITS=32 is    invalid for data type UInt16. Using NBITS=16
ERROR 1: JPEGSetupEncode:BitsPerSample 16 not allowed for JPEG
ERROR 1: JPEGSetupEncode:BitsPerSample 32 not allowed for JPEG
ERROR 1: C:/Users/xx/xx/DEM/newDEM compressed.tif, band 1: An error
occurred while writing a dirty block from GDALRasterBand::RasterIO
ERROR 1: JPEGSetupEncode:BitsPerSample 32 not allowed for JPEG
ERROR 1: JPEGSetupEncode:BitsPerSample 32 not allowed for JPEG**

I am using standard settings. I already tried with BIGTIFF and TILED Parameters, but did not help. I suppose it has to do with the JPEG compression settings, but I dont really know how to solve this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Set output data type to Byte

Comment: When I change the output date type to BYTE it seems to do something, but then the elevation data seems to be incorrect and it made a square out of my clipped shape.

I tried cliping again, but can not get rid of the area outside of my original shape.
I am new to QGIS and I hope someone could explain how to properly compress a TIFF file with QGIS?

Comment: Maybe this will help (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144962/creating-compressed-geotiff-with-qgis-clipper-tool)

Comment: You might instead right click on your tif layer and select Export, then Save Raster Layer As, and in the form scroll down to Profile and select JPEG compression.  You can click in the value box to change the amount of compression.  There are other settings but the default might be good enough for a first try.  All raster outputs are rectangular,  the area outside the clip shape would be no data or a color you can set to be transparent in the Layer-Properties-Transparency settings.

Comment: From the GDAL documentation about COMPRESS=JPEG https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html `JPEG should generally only be used with Byte data (8 bit per channel)`. Use some other compression method for your DEM.

Comment: @Adamski It sounds like changing to BYTE worked.  To remove the "skirt" change the Layer Styling, enter a nodata value (usually 0 if the skirt is black, or 255 if the skirt is white, depends on your data).  Then you can use the Raster Toolbar to visualize the range better.

Comment: 256 distinct values that BYTE datatype offers may be too few for a DEM but if the height range is not large it may be ok.

Comment: So using the ´output data to BYTE´ option I set the value of the area outside the clip 0 as transparent. I see some elevation data, but somehow the maximum elevation is now capped at 255?  I am supposed to have hills well over 300 m but now most of the area has an elevation of 255, except for a lower valley which is displayed correctly..

Comment: @johns I tried your suggestion, Saving the feature and adding JPEG compression, but this results in elevation values with many digits

Comment: @user30184 SO my solution has been to divide all the elevation values by 10, do the interpolation again and voila I have a DEM in 1/10 of a meter instead of meters.  Now When I compress this fyle using the output data as BYTE option I get a result. However the compression is way to much and I dont see any gradual changes anymore, its basically a new color for every 5 meter contour lines...

Comment: If I was working with a large DEM file I would use the GDAL Translate tool to convert to Int16 of Int32 (depending on the range of values you need) with the profile being set to high compression, which by default is Deflate, although you could change that to LZW.   If you don't want truncated values then you could multiply your values by 10 prior to the conversion, and then adjust your symbology in a map to "convert" that to meters, and/or divide your elevation by 10 in any analysis or another field to in effect convert back to meters.